# Pitch of 「見た目より」

Tags: pitch-accent

Consider the sentence

> 鈴木さんは&**見た目より**若く見えますね。
>
> Mr. Suzuki's not as old as he looks.

According to my dictionary:

- 見た目 has Atamadaka pitch
- より is a particle (so should be down-pitched here)

Yet according to [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index) placing these two words together causes 見た目 to have two accents(!?):

> [image]

As far as I knew, Japanese words can never have more than one accent?

**Question:** Is there something deep going on here, or is this just OJAD getting it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your dictionary is outdated, 見た目 is heiban in modern Japanese.
2. OJAD is also wrong, it’s parsing it as two separate words 見た+目 (the eye which saw).

It should be みためよ＼り.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I'm wondering if there is a way that will allow me to more clearly distinguish between 尾高 and 平板. As a problem I have a lot of self-awareness of, I often get the particle's pitch wrong. Sometimes I hear a fall on the particle but turns out there is no fall, as is the case here. I can't remember where I read it but a study put 平板 words through Audacity or something similar and the waveform shows a half-dropped particle. I seem to hear that with 平板 words. I can't seem to tell much difference between 見た目より and 花より. Would you have any suggestions for me to improve?